# Extract single columns from 2-column pdf

Tags: pdf

I have a pdf file in two-column format.  Is it possible to extract the text in a single-column format?  I realize that some parts of the document, such as page-wide illustrations, will require special treatment.

Comment: Are you talking something that automatically flies through and re-configures your document or something you can use to manually go through page by page yourself? If you mean manually, then you can use Libreoffice Draw(most likely already installed on your system)....... I've used it to select the entire 2nd column of a pdf and put it on a different page by itself. Just remember to "export as pdf" and rather than "save", to get your new pdf.

Answer (score 1):

[Briss](http://briss.sourceforge.net/) lets you select regions from overlayed pages to crop into separate pages using a GUI.

[image: briss preview]